# Keras Functional API changing layer names in every API

Tags: python, keras, model, neural-network, keras-layer

When I run the functional API in the model for k-fold cross-validation, the numbers in the naming the dense layer is increased in the return fitted model of each fold.
Like in the first fold it’s `dense_2_acc`, then in 2nd fold its `dense_5_acc`.

By my model summary shows my model is correct.  why is it changing the names in the fitted model `history` object of each fold?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really good question which shows something really important about `keras`. The reason why names change in such manner is that `keras` is not clearing previously defined variables even when you overwrite the model. You can easily check that variables are still in `session.graph` by calling:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.get_session().graph.get_collection('variables')
```

In order to clear previous model variables one may call:

```
K.clear_session()
```

However - be careful - as you might lose an existing model. If you want to keep names the same you can simply name your layers by adding `name` parameter to your layer instantiation, e.g.:

```
Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='output')
```

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Can you please take a look into this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900947/5904928
I am struggling for hours, couldn't find an answer.